# TI SN65HVD75 RS485 is not working while transmitting

Tags: rs485, texas-instruments

Now I am doing a project with [TI SN65HVD75 RS485](http://www.ti.com/product/SN65HVD75) and `nrf52832`.
The project is converting `RS485` to `BLE` or `BLE` to `RS485`.
I succeeded converting `RS485` to `BLE`. If other RS485 device sends datas to my device then my device will pass them to BLE.

But I can't transmit datas from BLE to other RS485 device through my device.

The circuit of my device is here.

[image]

Please, see `SN65HVD75DGK` part.
I use GPIOs of `nrf52832` like following.

- R : P0.14
- RE, DE : P0.15
- D : P0.16

I set `R` as pull-up by programming.
Before send datas from my device to other RS485 device, I set `RE`, `DE` as `HIGH`. But the datas are not passing.
I suspected `nrf52832`, so I tested `TI SN65HVD75 RS485` with `Arduino Due`.
But also datas from my device to other RS485 device are not passing with `Arduino Due`.

I think that I did wrong with `TI SN65HVD75 RS485`. But I don't know what it was.

Comment: Have you viewed the relevant signals on the SN65HVD75 (logic level data / enable & differential RS-485) using an oscilloscope, to help you narrow-down where the problem(s) is/are?

Comment: @SamGibson I viewed the relevant signals on the SN65HVD75. Without it UART signals are passing well. So I think that MCU, nrf52832, is normal. Also I have checked it with debugging F/W. Just in RS485 part datas are not passing.

Comment: Thank for the update. However that is not detailed enough for me to comment further. In order for me to do any further analysis, you would need to *update your question* and explain the *exact* tests that you did, and the *exact* waveforms of the signals that you measured. Also, there is a translation problem, because "*RS485 part datas are not passing*" (and similar phrases that you used which say "*passing*") are unclear - who or what is deciding about "passing"? Can you translate what you are trying to say any other way? In English we use terms like transmitting & receiving - not "passing".

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry. I am not familiar with English. As you said, RS485 part can receive datas but transmit datas. Why I am asking this question is that now I have to decide confirming a circuit diagram for manufacturing. I soldered SN65HVD75DGK by hand. So I think that that could cause this manfunction. I want experts like you to check my circuit and if they will say ok then I will confirm my circuit.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain in English :-) Unfortunately, the exact details of your problem (malfunction) are still unclear to me (e.g. "*RS485 part can receive datas but transmit datas.*" does not make sense to me :-( ). Therefore I don't know where to check *in detail* on the circuit diagram (schematic). Some RS-485 problems might even be caused by connection details which are not shown on the schematic, but I don't know if that could apply here. Due to these communications problems, I will stop now. Perhaps someone else will understand your description better than me. Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks. I will correct it.  
"RS485 part can receive datas but can't transmit datas"
Sorry. Now I'm finding solution myself.

Comment: @neosarchizo Do you observe timing characteristic of the driver? Remember that you can't send data immediately after you set DE high, and you also can't switch DE back to low immediately after sending last character (you need to wait until shift register spits the last bit). Check the table 7.7 in the datasheet. I suggest you to (only for testing) insert a something like 5ms delay after setting DE high (before sending first byte) and after sending last byte (before switching DE low).

Comment: @GAttuso That is the reason for this, but I inserted some delay  before and after transmition as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I used `TI SN65HVD75 RS485` and its operating voltage is 3.3V. And I tested it by `Arduino UNO` and `MAX485 module`. It works at 5V.
In `MAX485 module` there are `pull-up` and `pull-down` registers before `A` and `B`. But in my device there aren't registers before `A` and `B`.
I removed `pull-up` and `pull-down` registers in `MAX485 module`. After that my device can transmit datas and receive datas too.

Comment: A pedant writes: please don't be offended, but there's no such word as datas. Data is the plural of datum.

Comment: You should accept your answer so this question doesn't get bumped by Community.